# Diasble DiV on form load and enable the DIV on buttonClick using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html

i have a form in MVC,
it has a button which is visible and a DIV tag which is supposed to be not Visible on form load.

On click of this button, i want to make the content of this div tag visible.
Here, is the code>>

```
    <form id="DisplayComment" onload="hideTextBox()" >

        <label> Comment </label> <input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Add Comment" onclick="openTextBox();"/>

        <div id="manageTextBox" >
            <input type="text" id="commentBox"  name="enterComment" value="" /><br />
            <input type="button" id="addComment" name="addComment" value="Submit"/>
            <input type="button" id="cancelComment" name="cancelComment" value="Cancel"/>
        </div>
   </form>
```

i have two jquery , to disable the Div tag on form load and on button click to enable it. Here is the script>>

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function hideTextBox() {
                $("manageTextBox").prop("disabled", true);
            }

        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function openTextBox() {
                $("#manageTextBox").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        </script>
```

But they are not firing as expected. The onload of form does not fire. So the DIV tag is visible on page load. Help me fix this.

Comment: do you want to hide that div in form load? and show in button click?

Comment: yes -@tereško,   @CJ Ramki

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/22293414/2567813 this one is exactly what you need....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing id selector `$("manageTextBox").prop("disabled", true);`

Try with hide() and show()

You can use the click events of `submit` for that

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#manageTextBox").hide();

    $("#Submit").click(function () {
        $("#manageTextBox").show();
    });
    });
```

HTML

```
<form id="DisplayComment">

<label> Comment </label> <input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Add Comment"/>

<div id="manageTextBox" >
    <input type="text" id="commentBox"  name="enterComment" value="" /><br />
    <input type="button" id="addComment" name="addComment" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="button" id="cancelComment" name="cancelComment" value="Cancel"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As your objective is to disable the input elements try the below code.

```
<form id="DisplayComment">

        <label> Comment </label> <input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Add Comment" onclick="openTextBox();"/>

        <div id="manageTextBox" >
            <input type="text" id="commentBox"  name="enterComment" value="" /><br />
            <input type="button" id="addComment" name="addComment" value="Submit"/>
            <input type="button" id="cancelComment" name="cancelComment" value="Cancel"/>
        </div>
   </form>

// use this script if you want to disable the input elements
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(e){
          $("#manageTextBox *").prop("disabled", "disabled");
    });
    function openTextBox() {
          $("#manageTextBox *").prop("disabled", "");
    }
</script>
```

// use this for show/hide scenario

```
    $(document).ready(function(e){
          $("#manageTextBox").hide();
    });
    function openTextBox() {
          $("#manageTextBox").show();
    }
</script>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4FWH7/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQUery ready event

[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

From page:

While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

And also what other SOverflowers said you are missing id selector #

Comment: What single line? Are you viewing browser cache :)

Answer (score 0):

Div elements do not have a standard disabled attribute.

You are missing "#" in ur jquery selector.

Try this.

```
$("#manageTextBox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$("window").load(function(){
    $("manageTextBox").hide();
});

 $("#Submit").click(function () {
        $("#manageTextBox").show();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide div you should use styling instead and start with div syle property display:none. And as I understand after click you want div to be visible. You can use jquery show and hide functions. Here is the example:

```
<form id="DisplayComment">

<label> Comment </label> <input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Add Comment" onclick="openTextBox();"/>

<div id="comment" style="display: none" >
    <input type="text" id="commentBox"  name="enterComment" value="" /><br />
    <input type="button" id="addComment" name="addComment" value="Submit" onclick="hideTextBox();"/>
    <input type="button" id="cancelComment" name="cancelComment" value="Cancel" onclick="hideTextBox();"/>
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function hideTextBox() {
            jQuery("#comment").hide();
        }
        function openTextBox() {
            jQuery("#comment").show();
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just style the div to be hidden and change the style on click of the button from hidden to visible.

```
<script type"text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Submit").click(function () {
            debugger;
            $("#manageTextBox").css('visibility', 'visible');
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="DisplayComment">

    <label> Comment </label> <input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Add Comment"/>

    <div id="manageTextBox" style="visibility:hidden;" >
        <input type="text" id="commentBox"  name="enterComment" value="" /><br />
        <input type="button" id="addComment" name="addComment" value="Submit"/>
        <input type="button" id="cancelComment" name="cancelComment" value="Cancel"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .c1
        {

        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        function k()
        {
            $("#c1").show();
        }
        function hide()
        {
            $("#c1").hide();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="k()" />
        <div id="c1" style="display:none;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Enter Name</th>
                    <th>
                        <input id="Text1" type="text" />
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Enter Password</th>
                    <th>
                        <input id="Text1" type="text" />
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>
                        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="hide()" />
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should always support your answers with some explanation.